# routing in kubernetes... nginx proxy-pass, but with named ports

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have an application running in a cluster, where each user gets handed off to an individual pod. All user-pods run on the same port, so a nice simple nginx server can handle that.

If we assume that each user-pod is started with the equivalent of `docker run -name foo-<UUID> 1234:1234 user-pod`, we can construct a proxy to bounce from a url like `example.com/user/abcdef-123456-ghij` to a pod called `foo-abcdef-123456-ghij`, and map from port 80 to port 1234 :

```
location ~ /user/([a-z0-9]+) {
    << lots of stuff cut >>
    proxy_pass http://foo-$1.${POD_NAMESPACE}.svc.cluster.local:1234;
    proxy_set_header Host foo-$1:1234;
  }
```

There is a desire to add some *new* user-pods, which expose *different* ports.... and my nginx server can't do that.

Now, I know I can *name* the exposed ports in a pod [ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#field-spec-ports], and refer to them by name *within the cluster configuration* - so I could create definitions for the different user-pods, and *name* the `ports` the same, even though the `containerPort` value is different.... and the service definition would, I believe, happily map as needed.

Of course, the current nginx server, running in its own pod, knows nothing about these *names* - and complains about invalid port numbers if you try to use them.

My question is about switching to an nginx-ingress controller directly [rather than getting ingress to send the user to a pod to route] - can the nginx-ingress `path` handle *regexp* like its hosted sibling does?

Is

```
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: "/user/([a-z0-9]+)"
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: foo-$1
                port:
                  name: user-pod-exposed
```

a remotely valid concept?